# How to create polygon automatically with coordinates

Tags: polygon, point, coordinates, qgis-processing, unique-value

I have some bunch of points in an area and I want to draw connecting lines with the help of points to create a closed polygon. But all these needs manual efforts. Can any one explain to me how to create polygon automatically in QGIS with the help of outermost points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search for the words [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) in your preferred software documentation and you will probably figure it out yourself ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an automatic method for drawing connecting lines with the help of points to create a closed polygon. You are tagged this question with qgis-processing but convex hull, as suggested in a comment by @s.k, doesn't look as a good option because there are points not considered in final produced layer (I tested it). Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor) is a better option but some points can also be excluded in final product.

I suggest a semi automated approach with QGIS (completely automated requires Python) were you manually select contour points (in a clockwise sense) to be converted in a line and afterward in polygon. I tested my approach by digitizing such points in a new point layer (in your case you will use your original point layer and snapping options) from your image projected arbitrarily in EPSG:32612. It looks as follows (with only 18 points, as blue stars, digitized):

[image]

Afterward, I ran 'Points to path' processing tool for getting following result:

[image]

Finally, 'Lines to polygons' processing tool produces a desired result with Paths as input layer:

[image]